# Dual boot system: Grub doesn't detect Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub, linux-mint, bootloader

I have a dual boot system on a Lenovo G50-45 laptop with Windows 10 and Linux Mint 17.2. It worked fine briefly but after upgrading Linux, something broke it. Below, please find my boot-repair log. I'd appreciate any help that you may have. Thanks.

Paste2.org/6HXAdCxI
[Boot-repair log](http://paste2.org/6HXAdCxI)

Comment: Forgot to mention that Grub sees and boots fine to Mint but not Windows.

Answer (score 1):

What we have:

1. Disk is GPT style.
2. No EFI System partition.
3. Linux installed using MBR booting over sda2 - BIOS boot partition.

Suggested repairs:

1. Download Windows 10 and create installation/repair DVD/USB - Windows 10 can be downloaded from Microsoft - download .iso file. Use some Linux tool to transfer Windows 10 .iso to DVD or USB. Media should be UEFI bootable!
2. Boot Windows 10 DVD/USB the UEFI way - boot type can be selected in UEFI firmware.
3. Go to Repair - Advanced options - Command prompt.
4. Start diskpart.exe
5. Delete first 3 partitions - sda2 (/dev/sda2  2,050,048 2,582,527  532,480 BIOS Boot partition) also sda1 and sda3 (both size 2,048,000)
6. In freed space of disk create EFI System Partition - size at least 100 MB.
7. Reboot DVD/USB
8. Go to Recovery - "Automatic Repair". You have to run "Automatic Repair" eventually up to 3 times with rebooting after each run.

If steps above cannot fix Windows 10 booting you can try a last manual step on repair command prompt:

`bcdboot N:\windows` - where N: is your Windows 10 partition.

Next would be to reinstall Windows 10. (Once Windows 10 is installed on a device reinstallation does not require activation.)

Notes:

It would be interesting to see how diskpart.exe will list current partitioning and if Windows NTFS partition will be intact.

diskpart.exe has online help for commands (for example "help delete partition").